# Using refs to access components in React

Tags: reactjs

I am following a tutorial to understand how `React.js` works. I am stuck where using refs to access components. If anyone don't mind help look at my code and tell me where I am wrong. But, this is what I did. I have a general component `App` and html `Input` tag that update the `refs` in the `State`. But, I don't know why it's still showing `undefined`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0
    }
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  //To manage the state
  update(e) {
    this.setState({
      red: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.red.refs.inp).value,
      green: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.green.refs.inp).value,
      blue: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.blue.refs.inp).value
    })
    console.log(this.state); //<This is giving me Object {red: undefined, green: undefined, blue: undefined}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Slider ref="red" update={this.update}/>
        {console.log(this.state.red)} // This is undefined
        {this.state.red}
        <br />
        <Slider ref="green" update={this.update}/>
        {console.log(this.state.green)} // This is undefined
        {this.state.green}
        <br />
        <Slider ref="blue" update={this.update}/>
        {console.log(this.state.blue)} // This is undefined
        {this.state.blue}
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//Working with refs. Refs are a way of referencing components within our react application
class Slider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref="inp" type="range" min="0" max ="255" onChange={this.props.update}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('app')
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findDOMNode returns the corresponding native browser DOM element, which is in your case:

```
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max ="255" onChange={this.props.update} />
</div>
```

So you are reading the value of the div instead of the input.

Check this fix http://jsfiddle.net/69r5kn16/2/

Comment: Are you saying, it's reading the refs declared in the native browser and not the one being updated?

Comment: I think I now understand. Updated your answer. Gave the `input` a `ref`

Answer (score 3):

According to React [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) :

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" – instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Try this :

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            slider : 0,
        }
        this.update = (e) => {
            const {name,value} = e.target;
            this.setState({
                [name] : value,
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
                <Slider name="slider" update={this.update} />
                {this.state.slider}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class Slider extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (
            <div>
                <input name={this.props.name} type="range" min="0" max="255" onChange={this.props.update}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `refs`, you should use them after your component have been mounted, it means you should use them in `componentDidMount`.

I see you call `this.update` in your `Slider` Component. the order `componentDidMount` of child component and parentComponent is as follow:

```
componentWillMount Of parent
componentWillMount of child
componentDidMount of child
componentDidMount of Parent.
```

please check when do you call `update` method in your Slider Component.

Comment: Update is called here `<input type="range" min="0" max ="255" onChange={this.props.update}/>`. But, it's just an Component and it's a child of the `App Component`. Just declared outside

Comment: But, from my understanding of how `Javascript` works. For it to show `undefined`, it means it was being accessed before being declared. Which means I need to find out where it's being mounted right? But, then I'm new to React. I don't know where to find this